# Unusual output using *argv[]

Tags: c++, argv

I'm trying to print a string element of `argv[]` to the console but for whatever reason the output I get is, well, nonsense. My program, which tests for palindromes, seems to be working correctly. The only part that's off is when I attempt to output the element int `argv[]` to the console that I just tested to be a palindrome.

Here is my code that deals with this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    string s(argv[i]);
    printf("s: %s\n",s);
    if (ignoreCase) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s.size(); j++) {
            tolower(s.at(j));
        }
    }
    if (ignoreSpaces) {
        s = removeSpaces(s);
    }
    if (isPalindrome(s, 0, s.size() - 1)) {
        printf("%s is a palindrome.\n",s);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s is not a palindrome.\n",s);
    }
}
```

Here is the output I am getting:
[image]

Comment: can you share the error or the expected, and actual output?

Comment: @Saram ali Yes, I have updated my post. I meant to add it initially but I forgot

Comment: `printf("s: %s\n",s);` -- Don't do this.  The `printf` function knows nothing about `std::string`.  Your code as it stands invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie what do you recommend instead? I cannot use cout, as this is for an assignment (though this issue is not the learning objective) and that is a requirement

Comment: @McFizz -- *I cannot use cout* --??????? -- Now I've heard it all.  I've seen "I can't use vector" or "I can't use std::string" or "I can't use STL", but never this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Instructions dictate I cannot have `#include <iostream>` in my files, so I cannot use `cout`

Comment: If you must use `printf`, please be aware that `printf` only knows the arguments it is documented to know of.  C++ types such as `std::string` will not work -- you were lucky to even get your program to run to completion, since invalid arguments to `printf()` can lead to a crash.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind in the future. I looked over the documentation for `printf()` but I guess I didn't notice it was iffy about strings. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say you can't use `cout`, you're not using `printf` correctly.  You're using `printf` with arguments that `printf` does not know anything of (`std::string`), thus your program is invoking undefined behavior.

The fix is to use types that `printf` knows of.  Since `std::string` has a `c_str()` function that returns a `const char *`, use that instead.

So instead of lines like this:

```
printf("s: %s\n",s);
```

Do this:

```
printf("s: %s\n",s.c_str());
```

Comment: I had a feeling the issue was something along those lines. Thanks for clearing that up!